# RStudio R-package check note about missing repository

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-package

**Problem**

When I am using the package check provided by RStudio, I always get the note (and it's the only note) that no repository has been set and that therefore the cyclic dependency check is skipped. 
However, I do not get this note if I directly call

`devtools::check(args = c('--as-cran'))`

in R even though the same code is executed. Does anybody have an explanation for this issue?

**System Information**

- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
- OS: Ubuntu 15.04
- R version 3.2.1
- RStudio Version 0.99.473
- devtools 1.8.0
- Repository is set in .Rprofile via `options(repos = c(CRAN="https://cran.rstudio.com"))`

Answer (score 2):

Same Ubuntu 15.04 platform and R version etc pp -- but I set this in `Rprofile.site` and never get the note about the missing cyclic dependency:

```
## Example of Rprofile.site
local({
    r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.rstudio.com"
    r["eddelbuettel"] <- "http://eddelbuettel.github.io/drat"
    r["ghrr"] <- "http://ghrr.github.io/drat"
    options(repos = r)
})
```

I use two additional [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) repositories here but that is of course entirely optional.

(As an aside, this question like so many is flagged 'RStudio' but as best as I can tell this has nothing to do with where you call R from: be it RStudio, ESS or the command-line.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dirk. Adding the respective lines to `Rprofile.site` did not change that RStudio shows the mentioned note.
Also, the option 'repos' is set as it should be. It just seems that checking the package in RStudio gives that not but checking the package directly in R.

Comment: Shrug - - as I said, it all works for me in RStudio, ESS or on the command-line. I do not use devtools though so maybe try without that.